# How to register in unity passing a params array of two distinct types?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container, ioc-container, parameters

I'm new to Unity. So hopefully I'm asking the right thing because I'm still trying to grasp the proper way to implement DI and IoC. I'm trying to create a MVC5 site that initializes controllers with a specific constructor.

Here is what I am trying to do. I have a base controller that has a constructor that takes a params array of a certain type.

```
public abstract class DataModelController<TModel, TContext> : DataController<TContext>
    where TContext : OpenAccessContext,
                     new()
{
    public DataModelController(params IDataTransformer<TContext>[] dataTransformers) : base()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

I have two implementations of IDataTransformer< TContext> that I want to inject using unity all the time.

```
public class TrackCreatedTransformer : IDataTransformer<EntitiesModel>
{
    //...
}

public class TrackChangedTransformer : IDataTransformer<EntitiesModel>
{
    //...
}
```

Subsequently I have other implementations of IDataTransformer< TContext> that I need inject for specific implementations.

```
public class TrackClosedTransformer : IDataTransformer<EntitiesModel>
{
    //...
}

public class TrackSignedTransformer : IDataTransformer<EntitiesModel>
{
    //...
}
```

So here are three implementations of my abstract base controller:

```
public NormalModelController : DataModelController<NormalModel, EntitiesModel>
{
    public NormalModelController(params IDataTransformers<EntitiesModel>[] dataTransformers) : base()
    {
        //...
    }
}

public SpecialModelController : DataModelController<SpecialModel, EntitiesModel>
{
    public SpecialModelController(params IDataTransformers<EntitiesModel>[] dataTransformers) : base()
    {
        //...
    }
}

public AnotherSpecialModelController : DataModelController<AnotherSpecialModel, EntitiesModel>
{
    public AnotherSpecialModelController(params IDataTransformers<EntitiesModel>[] dataTransformers) : base()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

So I've been trying to figure out how to deal with the params array in unity and coming up short, basically where it would inject like so:

```
new NormalModelController(new TrackCreatedTransformer(), new TrackChangedTransformer());
```

And in other cases like so:

```
new SpecialModelController(new TrackCreatedTransformer(), new TrackChangedTransformer(), new TrackClosedTransformer());
new AnotherSpecialModelController(new TrackCreatedTransformer(), new TrackChangedTransformer(), new TrackSignedTransformer());
```

Comment: From a design perspective, I would say that your controllers should not know about the fact that there might be multiple transformers. Instead let them depend on a single `IDataTransformer<T>` and at runtime inject a [composite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) that will wrap zero, one, or more transformers. I however have no idea how to configure this with Unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this refactoring works for you.  Using composition over inheritance in this situation will work in your favor for the Unity registrations.  This is also complimentary to by @Steven's comment.

So here's a manager which is the composite transformer.  You'll notice that it implements IDataTransformer.  This is not strictly required, but it is helpful to ensure that your composite manager can perform every action that it delegates to its composite items.  The constructor takes in a selector (described in the next section) to filter the transformers down to only those that apply to this `TModel`.  It also takes in a params array of `IDataTransformer`.  As described later, you will get an instance of every IDataTransformer but construction of objects should be cheap and this should be negligible for performance.

```
public interface IDataTransformerManager<TModel, TContext> {}
public class DataTransformerManager<TModel, TContext> : 
    IDataTransformerManager<TModel, TContext>,
    IDataTransformer<TContext>
    where TContext : OpenAccessContext, new()
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IDataTransformer<TContext>> _transformers;

    public DataTransformerManager(
        IDataTransformerSelector<TModel, TContext> dataTransformerSelector, 
        params IDataTransformer<TContext>[] allTransformers)
    {
        _transformers = dataTransformerSelector.SelectTransformers(allTransformers);
    }
}
```

Next is the transformer selector.  Please customize this however you like, but its job is to filter the collection of all transformers down to only those that apply to the given `TModel`.

```
public interface IDataTransformerSelector<TModel, TContext>
    where TContext : OpenAccessContext, new()
{
    IEnumerable<IDataTransformer<TContext>> 
        SelectTransformers(IEnumerable<IDataTransformer<TContext>> allTransformers);
}

public class DataTransformerSelector<TModel, TContext> :
    IDataTransformerSelector<TModel, TContext>
    where TContext : OpenAccessContext, new()
{
    public IEnumerable<IDataTransformer<TContext>> 
        SelectTransformers(IEnumerable<IDataTransformer<TContext>> allTransformers)
    {
        // Custom logic to map the model type to the transformers that apply
        if (typeof(TModel) == typeof(NormalModel))
        {
            return allTransformers.Where(transformer =>
                transformer.GetType() == typeof(TrackCreatedTransformer) ||
                transformer.GetType() == typeof(TrackChangedTransformer)).ToArray();
        }

        if (typeof(TModel) == typeof(SpecialModel))
        {
            return allTransformers.Where(transformer =>
                transformer.GetType() == typeof(TrackCreatedTransformer) ||
                transformer.GetType() == typeof(TrackChangedTransformer) ||
                transformer.GetType() == typeof(TrackClosedTransformer)).ToArray();
        }

        if (typeof (TModel) == typeof (AnotherModel))
        {
            return allTransformers.Where(transformer =>
                transformer.GetType() == typeof (TrackCreatedTransformer) ||
                transformer.GetType() == typeof (TrackChangedTransformer) ||
                transformer.GetType() == typeof (TrackClosedTransformer) ||
                transformer.GetType() == typeof (TrackSignedTransformer)).ToArray();
        }

        throw new InvalidOperationException("Unknown model type: " + typeof(TModel));
    }
}
```

Now your controllers become quite clean (in my opinion).  You are no longer dependent on deriving from a custom type nor does your controller's constructor need to know the dependencies of the transformer manager constructor.  This will make unit testing with mocks much easier as well.

```
public class NormalModelController
{
    public NormalModelController(
        IDataTransformerManager<NormalModel, EntitiesModel> dataTransformerManager)
    {}
}

public class SpecialModelController
{
    public SpecialModelController(
        IDataTransformerManager<SpecialModel, EntitiesModel> dataTransformerManager)
    {}
}

public class AnotherModelController 
{
    public AnotherModelController(
        IDataTransformerManager<AnotherModel, EntitiesModel> dataTransformerManager)
    {}
}
```

Lastly is the Unity registration.  The IDataTransformerManager and the IDataTransformerSelector are registered using open generics, so Unity can resolve any generic type parameters of your choosing.  Then the IDataTransformers are registered with names to allow for multiple registrations with the same interface and to allow for the resolution of the params array in the manager constructor to get all instances.

```
private static void UnityRegistration(IUnityContainer container)
{
    container.RegisterType(
        typeof(IDataTransformerSelector<,>), 
        typeof(DataTransformerSelector<,>));
    container.RegisterType(
        typeof(IDataTransformerManager<,>),
        typeof(DataTransformerManager<,>));

    container.RegisterType<IDataTransformer<EntitiesModel>, TrackCreatedTransformer>
        ("TrackCreatedTransformer");
    container.RegisterType<IDataTransformer<EntitiesModel>, TrackChangedTransformer>
        ("TrackChangedTransformer");
    container.RegisterType<IDataTransformer<EntitiesModel>, TrackClosedTransformer>
        ("TrackClosedTransformer");
    container.RegisterType<IDataTransformer<EntitiesModel>, TrackSignedTransformer>
        ("TrackSignedTransformer");
}
```